# CakePHP Controller

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi I am adding a dynamic sub menu for CakePHP and get this error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: PagesController::$GamesRewiewTypes
```

I have created controller called `rewiew_types_controller.php` and it doesn't work??

App_Controller.php:

```
        $rewiewTypes = $this->GamesRewiewTypes->find('all', array('conditions' => array('GamesRewiewTypes.menu_show' => 1), 'order' => 'GamesRewiewTypes.title ASC'));

    $rewiewTypes = Set::combine($rewiewTypes, '{n}.GamesRewiewTypes.title', array('/reviews/{0}', '{n}.GamesRewiewTypes.id'));



    $mainMenu = array(

        '3dreviews' => $rewiewTypes,
    );
```

Rewiews_Type_Controller.php:

```
class RewiewTypesController extends AppController {
var $name = 'rewiewTypes';
var $uses = array('GamesRewiewTypes');
```

Pages_Controller.php:

```
class PagesController extends AppController {
var $uses = array('Banner');

public function index() {
    $banners = $this->Banner->find('all', array('order' => 'position ASC'));
    $this->set('banners', $banners);
    /*
    pr ($banners);
    exit;
    */
}
```

Comment: Have you mistyped `Rewiew` when you meant to type `Review`?

Comment: that is the previous coder and whole structure is mistyped inc database....

Comment: Heya mate, can you post some more code? You cant just use controllers by creating the file. You need to add it... And rewiew_types_controller misses Games somewhere anyways :D

Comment: okay so app_controller:  $rewiewTypes = $this->GamesRewiewTypes->find('all', array('conditions' => array('GamesRewiewTypes.menu_show' => 1), 'order' => 'GamesRewiewTypes.title ASC'));
  
  $rewiewTypes = Set::combine($rewiewTypes, '{n}.GamesRewiewTypes.title', array('/reviews/{0}', '{n}.GamesRewiewTypes.id'));

Comment: and:     $mainMenu = array(
            
  '3dreviews' => $rewiewTypes,
        );

Comment: Inside the controller: class RewiewTypesController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'rewiewTypes';
    var $uses = array('GamesRewiewTypes');

Comment: Well you are editing the app_controller, you should edit the pages_controller, which should be in app/controllers/ or if it isnt, copy it from cake/libs/controller/pages_controller.php . Add your $uses there.

Comment: not quite sure what to add there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace $uses in your app_controller and pages_controller with

```
var $uses = array('Banner','GamesRewiewTypes');
```

that should do the trick

Comment: thank you, now I have got Error: Notice (8): Undefined property: CakeErrorController::$GamesRewiewTypes [APP/app_controller.php, line 77]

Comment: Have you added the rewiew thingy to your app_controller too?

Comment: Np mate, I have been struggling with it before too :D

Answer (score 0):

You can load the model within the function

```
public function someFunc(){ 
   $this->loadModel('Model1','Model2');
   //todo
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  What is the connection between `Model1` and `Model2` in your answer and the `PagesController::$GamesRewiewTypes` mentioned by the original poster?  Thanks!